# incorrect permissions when home directory is automatically created in FreeIPA

Tags: linux, redhat, identity-management, freeipa

I have configured an IPA domain for my systems and also enabled automatically creating home directory when user logs in with --enablemkhomedir option.
the problem I have is whenever a user logs in, a home directory will create for it with 755 permission.but I want the permission to be 700.
How do i fix this?
I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... looking into a fix. Also, this probably belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a RHEL or CentOS-like system, this is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=995097), detailed in: [Red Hat 995097](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=995097).

The fix that I have in place is to use the oddjobd process to create directories, rather than the legacy `pam_mkhomedir`.

So if you don't already have it, `yum install oddjob-mkhomedir`.

From there, you can edit the mask in `/etc/oddjobd.conf.d/oddjobd-mkhomedir.conf`

Modify the two entries:

```
    <method name="mkmyhomedir">
      <helper exec="/usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir -u 0002"
              arguments="0"
              prepend_user_name="yes"/>
      <!-- no acl entries -> not allowed for anyone -->
    </method>

    <method name="mkhomedirfor">
      <helper exec="/usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir -u 0002"
```

to:

```
    <method name="mkmyhomedir">
      <helper exec="/usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir -u 0077"
              arguments="0"
              prepend_user_name="yes"/>
      <!-- no acl entries -> not allowed for anyone -->
    </method>

    <method name="mkhomedirfor">
      <helper exec="/usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir -u 0077"
```

Restart `oddjobd` and make sure it's chkconfig'd on.

You may also need to restart `sssd`.

Also see: http://tech.lanesnotes.com/2010/11/ad-authentication-with-rhel-6.html